# An efficient compiler compiles to the exact same result every time?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, interpreter

I would ask a question regarding compilers, specifically how they work. I would believe that compilers would always compile to the same machine code for code that is written differently syntactically but does the same thing. Is this true? Does functionally similar code get compiled to the same result regardless of syntactical differences?

for example:

```
int number = 2;
```

would compile to the same thing as:

```
int number;
number = 2;
```

or that

```
while True:
```

would be the same as (i'm using python here as an example):

```
while 1:
```

I am particularly interested in the .net compilers and interpreters. does the JIT compiler compile "in time" to the same thing every time? Do interpreters like the Python interpreter "interpret" the code code exactly the same every time?

thanks!

Comment: how are the two for loops the same??

Comment: What do you mean by "does the same thing?"  The last two loops you have actually do different things, since even though they loop five times each the values of i during the loop are different.

Comment: It's possible that `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` might get compiled to the same object code as `for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)` under certain circumstances, but in the general case you *don't* want it to since `i` will have a different range of values.  If `i` gets used inside the loop, that difference will matter.

Comment: Sorry, i changed the code, instead of the for loop, I changed it to a python while loop. The two for loops were not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int number = 2;
```

would compile to the same thing as:

```
int number; number = 2;
```

Probably but not certainly. NB in many languages the declaration doesn't generate any code at all.

or that for

```
(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

would be the same as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
```

Certainly not! Different semantics!

NB this is not an 'efficiency' consideration.

> does the JIT compiler compile "in time" to the same thing every time?
>   Do interpreters like the Python interpreter "interpret" the code code
>   exactly the same every time?

Now you seem to be asking a completely different question. The same source code is always compiled the same way, modulo JIT effects, and interpreted the same way. Computers are deterministic.

Comment: Computers might be deterministic, but compilers are generally allowed a great deal of leeway. So long as the resulting program is functionally correct then pretty much any way of achieving that is fair game. (Different language specifications determine what constitutes "functional correctness" and what is allowed to be implementation-specific. For example, the C# spec is a lot tighter than the C++ spec with regards to what a spec-compliant program is and isn't allowed to do.)

Comment: @LukeH Agree completely. It's not at all clear what the OP is asking in his final para.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if my wording was confusing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the particular rules the compiler follows happen to produce the same output for two different inputs.

The authors of the compiler don't make any guarantees in this regard.  (I'm not anything close to an expert, but I suspect that the problem of determining whether two programs are observably identical is similar to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

Comment: It is undecidable, which is the term you're looking for.  But for many cases, you can easily prove equivalence.  Then again, there are always strange edge cases, do you want a hardware loop on a microcontroller -- intended to create a delay -- to be optimized out?  Probably not..

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: Surely any program of non-trivial complexity quickly becomes too difficult to reason about?

Comment: Not true at all, consider loop hoisting and algebraic optimizations, and newer whole program optimizers.  A whole field of compilers research and decision procedures have built up around this.  Vectorizers, the omega test, etc... all of these tools make it possible to reason about complex patterns of code.  You can't typically swap one algorithm for another, but you can do quite a bit beyond what a human would see.

Answer (score 0):

In general - no, because a compiler which gave that guarantee would be able to compile any program which doesn't halt into a simple infinite loop (`while(true);`).

Doing so would constitute a solution to the halting problem, which is impossible for a turing complete language.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, compilers will try to emit the same object code for a given input *for the same compiler settings*. Different flags, especially optimization levels, will change the output.

The compiler produces an internal representation of the code supplied to it (an 'intermediate representation', IR), generally as a tree (http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node23.html), which it then manipulates to produce better code. Your example of

```
int number;
number = 2;
```

vs.

```
int number = 2;
```

is a good one: the two code snippets would produce different IRs, but the compiler would transform the first, more complex, IR into the second one. Modern compilers can do much more sophisticated transformations, simplifying code in ways a human would find very difficult, but they can't do it in every case - you'll always be able to find two semantically equivalent programs that don't compile to the same code.

For much, much more, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design. It's a fascinating topic and one well worth reading up on.